# How to convert an object of parallel lists to a list of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an object like

```
var data = [
   {
      "Name": ["Jane", "Peter", "Jenny"],
      "Id": [1, 2, 3],
      "Years": [16, 17, 18]
    }
];
```

But I want to put it to a react table which need another format like it

```
var data1 = [
  {
     "Name": "Jane",
     "Id": 1,
     "Years": 16,
   },
   {
      "Name": "Peter",
      "Id": 2,
      "Years": 17,
    },
    {
       "Name": "Jenny",
       "Id": 3,
       "Years": 18,
     }
]
```

How can I conversion it with JSX?

Comment: You would probably write some code. What have you tried?

Comment: What should happen if the arrays in `Name`, `Id` and `Years` don't have the same number of items?

Comment: @Phil I think it will not happen , it will put `0` to make the same number of items

Comment: Better to write robust code in case it doesn't.

Comment: @RobG I use for loop in react like it 
`for (i = 0; i < data[0]["Name"].length; i++) {
    text += "{'Name':'"+data[0]["Name"][i] + "',
              'Id':'"+data[0]["Id"][i]+"',
              'Years':'"+data[0]["Years"][i]+"'},";
}`
but it can't work in  react ,maybe I need to use map function?

Comment: Putting it here incase lodash/underscoreJS can be used and properties are static.

`_.zip(data["Name"], data["Id"], data["Years"]).map(function(d){ return {Name: d[0], Id: d[1], Years: d[2]}; })`

Comment: @Adrian note, `data` is an array, not an object literal

Comment: @phil How can I to prevent it ?

Comment: @DanaChen see my answer below. I've used `null` as the default value to fill in any missing array indices but you can use whatever you want

Comment: *"How can I conversion it with JSX?"* - You wouldn't use any JSX features to do the conversion, you'd use plain JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd find out the maximum property length (in case they aren't all the same), create an array of that size, iterate in a for-loop, create objects using the data *keys* and matching index positions (`null` if there's no match) and push them into the array.

```js
const data = [{
  "Name": ["Jane", "Peter", "Jenny"],
  "Id": [1, 2, 3],
  "Years": [16, 17, 18]
}]

const interestingData = data[0]
const keys = Object.keys(interestingData)

const maxItems = keys.reduce((count, key) => Math.max(count, interestingData[key].length), 0)

const transformed = new Array(maxItems)
for (var i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
  transformed[i] = keys.reduce((obj, key) => Object.assign(obj, {
    [key]: interestingData[key][i] || null // default value if no matching index
  }), Object.create(null))
}

console.info(transformed)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the pretty much straight forward implementation for your problem. For iteration, I have considered the length of **Name** array inside the object.

```js
var data = [{
  "Name": ["Jane", "Peter", "Jenny"],
  "Id": [1, 2, 3],
  "Years": [16, 17, 18]
}];

var data1 = [ ];

var iterations = data[0].Name.length;

var requiredData = data[0];

var keyArray = Object.keys(requiredData);


for ( var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ) {
    tempObj = { };
    for (var key of keyArray) {
        tempObj[key] = requiredData[key][i];
    }
    data1.push(tempObj);
}

console.log('data1 = ', data1)
```